# Matrix creation with list index out of range?

Tags: python, list, matrix, python-2.6

I'm trying to create a 3x10x10 matrix, and I feel like I've done it right. I'm trying to get the `GridSet` function to set all the values for me, and I'm getting an error that is "List index out of range" at line 7. I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

If there's a better way of creating the matrix without having tons of square brackets (without modules, I've heard of NumPy but I want to do this barebones) that would be good to know.

I'm running 2.6.x, not exactly sure which version. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

def GridSet(fullGrid):
    letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
    for j in range(10):
        for i in range(10):
            fullGrid[j][i][0].append(letters[j]+str(i+1))
            fullGrid[j][i][1].append(random.randrange(100)+1)
            fullGrid[j][i][2].append(0)


#main
fullGrid = [[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],        [],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]]
filledGrid = GridSet(fullGrid)
print filledGrid
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668341/create-3d-array-using-python    You can do python -v to find your version of Python as well.

Comment: @Joe it turns out that is the problem. But I can't figure it out. The format I have is [Opens the whole list(x10) [Opens the second list (x10)[Opens the third list (x3)]]]

Comment: There is an issue with how you defined fullGrid (way at bottom). What happens if you tell it to just print fullGrid[0][0][0] just before the loop? You'll get list index out of range as well. Your list is defined right now as 2x2, not a 3x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following nested list comprehension should create the original list:

```
In [13]: [[[None for i in range(3)] for j in range(10)] for k in range(10)]
Out[13]: 
[[[None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None]],
 [[None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  [None, None, None],
  ... etc
```

Although you could create the entire thing instead of creating the list first and then populating it:

```
In [23]: l = [[[letters[j]+str(i+1), random.randrange(100)+1, 0] for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
In [24]: pprint(l)
[[['a1', 82, 0],
  ['a2', 77, 0],
  ['a3', 64, 0],
  ['a4', 34, 0],
  ['a5', 95, 0],
  ['a6', 69, 0],
  ['a7', 4, 0],
  ['a8', 72, 0],
  ['a9', 83, 0],
  ['a10', 100, 0]],
 [['b1', 19, 0],
  ['b2', 59, 0],
  ['b3', 15, 0],
   ...
```

Comment: I'm seeing 10 (0,9) letters in the `letter` list. Am I looking wrong? ;)

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused. Is this what you try to achieve?

```
import random

def GridSet():
    fullGrid = []
    letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

    for j in range(10):
        collect = []
        for i in range(10):
            collect_sub = []
            collect_sub.append([letters[j] + repr(i+1), random.randrange(100)+1, 0])
            collect.append(collect_sub)
        fullGrid.append(collect)

    return fullGrid

filledGrid = GridSet()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(filledGrid)
```

**Output**

```
[[[['A1', 12, 0]],
  [['A2', 99, 0]],
  [['A3', 91, 0]],
  [['A4', 29, 0]],
  [['A5', 72, 0]],
  [['A6', 24, 0]],
  [['A7', 99, 0]],
  [['A8', 77, 0]],
  [['A9', 39, 0]],
  [['A10', 93, 0]]],
 [[['B1', 54, 0]],
  [['B2', 78, 0]],
  [['B3', 12, 0]],
  [['B4', 78, 0]],
  [['B5', 79, 0]],
  [['B6', 68, 0]],
  [['B7', 80, 0]],
  [['B8', 29, 0]],
  [['B9', 60, 0]],
  [['B10', 48, 0]]],
 [[['C1', 59, 0]],
  [['C2', 20, 0]],
  [['C3', 4, 0]],
  [['C4', 42, 0]],
  [['C5', 91, 0]],
  [['C6', 61, 0]],
  [['C7', 28, 0]],
  [['C8', 68, 0]],
  [['C9', 18, 0]],
  [['C10', 73, 0]]],
 [[['D1', 9, 0]],
  [['D2', 29, 0]],
  [['D3', 81, 0]],
  [['D4', 46, 0]],
  [['D5', 49, 0]],
  [['D6', 95, 0]],
  [['D7', 64, 0]],
  [['D8', 5, 0]],
  [['D9', 26, 0]],
  [['D10', 88, 0]]],
 [[['E1', 62, 0]],
  [['E2', 6, 0]],
  [['E3', 35, 0]],
  [['E4', 37, 0]],
  [['E5', 54, 0]],
  [['E6', 58, 0]],
  [['E7', 85, 0]],
  [['E8', 26, 0]],
  [['E9', 76, 0]],
  [['E10', 85, 0]]],
 [[['F1', 38, 0]],
  [['F2', 67, 0]],
  [['F3', 32, 0]],
  [['F4', 2, 0]],
  [['F5', 76, 0]],
  [['F6', 97, 0]],
  [['F7', 34, 0]],
  [['F8', 30, 0]],
  [['F9', 58, 0]],
  [['F10', 73, 0]]],
 [[['G1', 68, 0]],
  [['G2', 20, 0]],
  [['G3', 60, 0]],
  [['G4', 46, 0]],
  [['G5', 89, 0]],
  [['G6', 85, 0]],
  [['G7', 76, 0]],
  [['G8', 58, 0]],
  [['G9', 86, 0]],
  [['G10', 49, 0]]],
 [[['H1', 22, 0]],
  [['H2', 76, 0]],
  [['H3', 50, 0]],
  [['H4', 2, 0]],
  [['H5', 6, 0]],
  [['H6', 60, 0]],
  [['H7', 92, 0]],
  [['H8', 9, 0]],
  [['H9', 26, 0]],
  [['H10', 91, 0]]],
 [[['I1', 57, 0]],
  [['I2', 89, 0]],
  [['I3', 1, 0]],
  [['I4', 7, 0]],
  [['I5', 25, 0]],
  [['I6', 70, 0]],
  [['I7', 40, 0]],
  [['I8', 21, 0]],
  [['I9', 7, 0]],
  [['I10', 93, 0]]],
 [[['J1', 77, 0]],
  [['J2', 23, 0]],
  [['J3', 24, 0]],
  [['J4', 48, 0]],
  [['J5', 17, 0]],
  [['J6', 64, 0]],
  [['J7', 11, 0]],
  [['J8', 33, 0]],
  [['J9', 23, 0]],
  [['J10', 20, 0]]]]
```

If the indent is one too deep, you just remove an append to the `fullGrid` without damaging the rest of the integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better description, but I just want to write what could easily be a one-liner to solve what I think you are looking for.

```
import random

def GridSet(letters):
    letRange = range(len(letters))
    return [ [[letter for letter in letters] for v in letRange], 
             [[random.randrange(100)+1 for i in letRange] for v in letRange], 
             [[0 for i in letRange] for v in letRange] ]

grid = GridSet(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"])

# len(grid):  3
# len(grid[0]):  10
# len(grid[0][0]):  10
```